# the map from the horizontal bundle is a submersion or an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\pi \colon M \to B$ be a riemannian submersion and $g$ the metric on $M$. Then we get the vertical subspace $ \mathcal{V}_x = \ker d_x \pi$ and the horizontal subspace $\mathcal{H}_x= \mathcal{V}_x^\perp$ as the orthogonal space of $\mathcal{V}_x$ in $T_xM$. 
Now these subspace form the vertical and horizontal bundle and $TM = \mathcal{V} \oplus \mathcal{H}$.

Now considering the map $\pi_* \colon \mathcal{H} \to TB$ as a smooth map between manifolds, is it possible to conclude, that $\pi_*$ is a submersion? Is it a submersion?

More precicsely, I'm having a Lie group $G$ acting properly, freely and by isometries on $M$ and $\pi \colon M \to B =M/G$ is just the quotient manifold, endowed with the submersion metric. I showed that $\pi_* \colon \mathcal{H}/G \to TB$ is a smooth map, which is bijective. But I want to show that it is a diffeomorphisms, Therefore it is necessary and sufficient that $\pi_*$ is a submersion or immersion. But I don't know how to prove this fact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Riemannian manifolds, so I hope this makes sense. I don't know how standard the terminology is in my course, so I'll start with the definitions I've heard.

Definition:
If $(\widetilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ and $(M,g)$ are Riemannian manifolds, and $\pi : \widetilde{M} \to M$ is *smooth submersion*, the map $\pi$ is said to be a **Riemannian submersion** if 
\begin{equation} \tag{1} 
\tilde{g}_{x}(v,w) = g_{\pi(x)}(d_{x} \pi(v), d_{x} \pi (w)) \text{ for all }v,w \in \mathcal{H}_{x}
\end{equation}

Claim 1: Since $\mathcal{H}_{x}$ is a vector space, it follows that $d_{x} \pi \big|_{\mathcal{H}_{x}}$ is in fact a linear vector space isometry (that is a linear, injective and surjective map that preserves the respective distance between vectors) from $\mathcal{H}_{x} \to M_{\pi(x)}$.

Indeed, since $d_{x} \pi$ is definitely linear, and preserves Equation (1) shows it preserves distances, we only need to show that it is bijective.

Let $u,v \in \mathcal{H}_{x}$ be such that $d_{x} \pi(u) = d_{x} \pi(v)$. Then $d_{x}\pi(u-v) = 0$. But, $u-v \in \mathcal{H}_{x}$ so $\tilde{g}_{x}(u-v, u-v) = g_{\pi(x)} ( d_{x} \pi(u-v), d_{x} \pi(u-v)) = 0$. So, $u = v$ by the non-degeneracy condition of inner products. Hence $d_{x} \pi$ is injective.

On the other hand, by definition of $\pi$ being a smooth submerssion, we know that $d_{x} \pi$ is surjective. So, for $u \in T_{\pi(x)} M$ there exists $v \in T_{x} \widetilde{M}$ such that $d_{x} \pi(u) = v$. One can uniquely write $u = u^{H} + u^{V}$ where $u^{H} \in \mathcal{H}_{x}$ and $u^{V} \in \mathcal{V}_{x}$. But, by definition of $\mathcal{V}_{x}$ it follows that $d_{x} \pi(u^{V}) = 0$. So, by linearity of $d_{x} \pi$ we know that $v = d_{x} \pi(u) = d_{x} \pi(u^{H})$. Hence, $d_{x} \pi \big|_{\mathcal{H}_{x}}$ is also surjective. Hence Claim 1 has been shown.

Since $\mathcal{H} = \sqcup_{x \in \widetilde{M}} \mathcal{H}_{x}$ is embedded in $T \widetilde{M}$, it follows that $\pi_{*} = \pi \big|_{\mathcal{H}}$ is still smooth. So Claim 1 guarantees that $d_{x} \pi_{*} : \mathcal{H}_{x} \to T_{\pi(x)}M$ is a linear vector space isomorphism for all $x \in \widetilde{M}$ it follows that $\pi_{*}$ is both a submerssion and an immersion.